# How do I import a specific line from a text file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, load

I'm building an app to import data from a text file to a database.

I want to import only specific lines from the text file.  With Navicat I found that we could limit number of line when importing data.

I also found an article saying that we could limit it, so I tried this:

```
load data infile 'c:/coop/wkwk.txt' into table jo fields 
    terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n' limit 10,100;
```

But I get an error in `SQL syntax`, what is the `QUERY` to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Unix/Linux you could try using a fifo buffer:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mysql.pipe 
# Select rows 101 to 110
sed -n 101,110p filename > /tmp/mysql.pipe & 
mysql –uusername -p -Ddatabasename -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ' /tmp/mysql.pipe ' INTO TABLE tablename"

rm -f /tmp/mysql.pipe
```

Comment: This is a very bold answer. +1 because I like bold !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `LIMIT` on `LOAD DATA INFILE`. The only thing you can do, with regard to your question, is to skip a certain number of rows:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO TABLE ... IGNORE 17 LINES
```

But you then have no way stopping until the end of file. See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).